# How to create multiple jars based on the different versions of dependent jars using maven

Tags: maven, jar

I have the requirement of creating multiple jars from a single pom.xml file based on the different versions of dependent jars.

Please have a look on below pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>javar1-test</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>JAVAR 1.0: TEST</name>
    <description>Classes to test multiple jars creation</description>
    <properties>
        <javar.version>[4.4.8,)</javar.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>renJar</groupId>
            <artifactId>rebJarClientWS</artifactId>
            <version>${javar.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>renJar</groupId>
            <artifactId>recJarClientWS</artifactId>
            <version>${javar.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>${project.artifactId}-2.0-${javar.version}</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>${project.artifactId}-2.0-${javar.version}</finalName>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${javar.version}</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here, in pom.xml I have tried specifying different versions of dependent jars using `<javar.version>[4.4.8,)</javar.version>`(In the repository I have dependent jars with different versions from 4.4.8 to 4.4.10) after building, multiple jars are not created for the different versions of dependent jars.
I want to create multiple jars using above pom.xml, where each jar will be created with one version of dependent jars.

E.g. -  I want to create below three jars from above pom.xml :
a. javar1-test-2.0-4.4.8.jar - dependent on rebJarClientWS-4.4.8.jar and recJarClientWS-4.4.8.jar

b. javar1-test-2.0-4.4.9.jar - dependent on rebJarClientWS-4.4.9.jar and recJarClientWS-4.4.9.jar

c. javar1-test-2.0-4.4.10.jar - dependent on rebJarClientWS-4.4.10.jar and recJarClientWS-4.4.10.jar

Thanks

Comment: You should define the dependency simply as `<scope>provided</scope>` so the user of your lib can decided which version he/she will use...No need to define a version range nor the strange construct to create a jar with different versions which will not work that way...

Comment: Don't we have any approach that will create multiple jars based on dependent jars version? The idea is to build multiple jars at once and later in some other project we can use javar1-test-2.0-xxx.jar with rebJarClientWS-xxx.jar and recJarClientWS-xxx.jar. where xxx might be any version like 4.4.8 or 4.4.9 and etc..

Comment: Simply use the provided approach which is simpler...Furthermore if you like to build things you like to have you need to have a separate module for each different version of the dependency...cause the pom describes the dependencies...